# Ethernet controller

Tags: networking, ethernet, nic

My Ethernet interface doesn't work: when I insert my ethernet cable, the port blinks but nothing happens to my connections. My wifi card is functional. So was my Ethernet when I used to run Windows 10.

After running `sudo modprobe e1000e && dmesg | grep e100` the result was:

```
[    0.094417] pci 0000:01:00.0: reg 0x18: [mem 0xee100000-0xee10ffff]
[    0.104039] pci 0000:00:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xee100000-0xee1fffff] 
[    0.203751] pci 0000:00:01.0:   bridge window [mem 0xee100000-0xee1fffff]
[    0.203935] pci_bus 0000:01: resource 1 [mem 0xee100000-0xee1fffff]
[    3.206159] e1000e: Intel(R) PRO/1000 Network Driver - 3.2.6-k
[    3.206162] e1000e: Copyright(c) 1999 - 2015 Intel Corporation.
[    3.206214] e1000e 0000:02:00.0: Disabling ASPM  L1
[    3.206217] e1000e 0000:02:00.0: can't disable ASPM; OS doesn't have ASPM control
[    3.206455] e1000e 0000:02:00.0: Interrupt Throttling Rate (ints/sec) set to dynamic conservative mode
[    3.263128] e1000e 0000:02:00.0: The NVM Checksum Is Not Valid
[    3.300313] e1000e: probe of 0000:02:00.0 failed with error -5
```

Output for `sudo lshw -C Network`:

```
*-network UNCLAIMED     
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: 82573L Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ee000000-ee01ffff ioport:3000(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: AR5212 802.11abg NIC
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: ap0
       version: 01
       serial: 00:19:7e:a1:f1:ad
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath5k driverversion=4.15.0-58-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.12.1 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:17 memory:edf00000-edf0ffff
  *-network:0
       description: Wireless interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: wls3
       serial: 00:19:7e:a1:f1:ac
       capabilities: ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath5k driverversion=4.15.0-58-generic firmware=N/A link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
  *-network:1
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enp0s29f7u1i5
       serial: a6:45:64:ad:da:45
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=cdc_ether driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=ZTE CDC Ethernet Device link=no multicast=yes
```

Comment: So the "UNCLAIMED" message means no driver is assigned to that interface yet. Which version of Ubuntu are you running and does your wifi work? Also, what model computer is it? If you have wi-fi, try `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` and restart. Make sure you have your software sources enabled too.

Comment: Please run the terminal command: `sudo modprobe e1000e && dmesg | grep e100` Next, edit your question to show the result. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I did exactly that: running  `sudo modprobe e1000e && dmesg | grep e100`  and the results shown in my question. The ethernet port blinks when ethernet cable inserted.

Comment: Please add output of the command `sudo lshw -C network`.